# How to align labels differently in listview

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, label

I have 2 labels in a `ListView`.
1st label is an `ItemName` (with vertical align to start),
and the 2nd label is `ItemDescription` (with vertical align to end).

What I'm trying to achieve is...
When `ItemDescription` is empty, I want the `ItemName` to be vertical align to center

Since I'm new, it will be great if you can also show an example.

This is my Xaml (ItemsPage)

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding _items, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="lstView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="0,0,8,0" Margin="3,0,3,0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3"></Image>

                        <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>

                        <Label Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="End"></Label>
                
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IValueConverter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

```
<Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" MaxLines="1" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="{Binding ItemDescription,Converter={StaticResource checkItemDescription}}"></Label>
```

**Converter**

```
public class AlignmentConverter : IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
    CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value==null)
            return LayoutOptions.Start;

        return LayoutOptions.End; 

    }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
    CultureInfo culture)
    {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your reply was really helpful. I really appreciate that. The only thing I changed was `TextAlignment` instead of `LayoutOptions` (I don't know if its really matter) and it works perfectly fine. thank you again

Comment: Congrats @Noah! Happy to hear that!